I am using Azure App Configuration Services with ASP.NET Core with LogLevel configurations but Entity Framework Core and HostingLifetime shows null
I am writing an ASP.NET Core 8.0 application and trying to use Azure App Configuration services.
I am starting off trying to move the logging aspects out of appsettings.json.
I have the following as keys within Azure App Configuration services:

Logging:LogLevel:Default
Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft
Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft:EntityFrameworkCore
Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft:HostingLifetime

I have the following configuration class:
public class LogLevelConfiguration
{
    public const string LogLevel = "Logging:LogLevel";
    public string? Default { get; set; }
    public string? Microsoft { get; set; }

    public string? EntityFrameworkCore { get; set; }
    public string? HostingLifetime { get; set; }
}

In my Program.cs, I have the following code to get the section:
app.Configuration.GetSection(Logging:LogLevel).Bind(loggingLevels);

When I run the app I get the correct values for Micrososft and Default but I get nulls for EntityFrameworkCore and HostingLifetime.
What do I need to change?

As per your scenario and description, ensure your LogLevelConfiguration class uses a dictionary for Microsoft log levels, allowing access to specific keys like EntityFrameworkCore and HostingLifetime. In your Program.cs, bind to the Logging:LogLevel section and access these keys through the dictionary, ensuring that the keys in Azure App Configuration match the structure required. If issues persist, consider logging the configuration to verify the loaded values.

Those keys don't look correct; the last segment represents the namespace that must have dots instead of colons, so e.g. Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime. Similar for the other one.

@MdFaridUddinKiron Why do I need a dictionary when there are properties in the LogLevelConfiguration for each element?

@pfx I understand that is what is in the appsettings.json.  I am just trying to figure out how to map the keys/values in App Configuration Services to the POCO objects.  I shouldn't have to have Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime as the key in App Config Services do I?

If you want to log levels to also take effect on the running application, they should be correct. Besides that, because of the colon in Microsoft:HostingLifetime there's no match with the MicrosoftHostingLifetime property. You might give it a try to put a [ConfigurationKeyName("Microsoft:HostingLifetime")] attribute on that property as more or less explained here.

@pfx It worked!!

@pfx - Please post your comments as an answer.
